# how would i change the text color without the text having a class?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to change make the text display/change color but so far all I can do is change width and height, which doesn't really affect anything in my current situation.

HTML:

```
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist">by USAO, Laur</div>
```

CSS:

```
.size12-3cLvbJ.subtext-3CDbHg.spotify-artist {
  display: inline;
  height: 15px;
  width: 165px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

The display: inline and background-color don't really affect anything. I've tried `color: #FFFFFF;` but that didn't do anything either

Comment: You can use inline style like this: 
`<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist" style="color: #ffffff;">by USAO, Laur</div>`
or try to move your class name to the end of list of classes:
`<div class="subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist size12-3cLvbJ">by USAO, Laur</div>
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color:`  is indeed the way to go. If your `color` is not taking effect, there can be **only** be three culprits:

- You have cached the old stylesheet. Try a hard refresh with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
- You have incorrectly referenced the stylesheet. Ensure the reference is correct, and other styles appear.
- The third is the most likely culprit, a problem of [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). This means that you are correctly applying the style, but it is being **overridden**. Ensure that you don't have any other rules affecting the colour of the element, and apply more specificity if needed.

CSS rules should always be added with the **lowest possible specificity**:

- First try the element
- Then try the class
- Then try the ID
- *Then* resort to inline styles
- **Finally** resort to `!important` declarations

Base level specificity can be seen applying the style correctly here:

```css
.size12-3cLvbJ.subtext-3CDbHg.spotify-artist {
  display: inline;
  height: 15px;
  width: 165px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  color: red; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist">by USAO, Laur</div>
```

Here is an extended example with colours conflicting:

```css
.size12-3cLvbJ.subtext-3CDbHg.spotify-artist {
  display: inline;
  height: 15px;
  width: 165px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  color: red; /* Added */
}

div {
  color: blue; /* Applied, but not specific enough */
}
```

```html
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist">by USAO, Laur</div>
<div>Example</div>
```

You can see this happening by inspecting the element in the F12 Developer Tools (note the strikethrough):

[image: F12]

Comment: apparently I had the opacity getting set to 0 somewhere else, thanks to this I found it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> how would i change the text color without the text having a class?

Try an inline style, which overrides class styles

```html
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist" style="color:red">by USAO, Laur</div>
```

You can also use the `font` tag, although be warned support for it was deprecated in HTML5 and support for it across browsers will likely be dropped soon.

```html
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist"><font color="red">by USAO, Laur</font></div>
```

> I'm trying to theme something so all i have is CSS

Use the `color` attribute. For example:

```css
.spotify-artist{
  color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="size12-3cLvbJ subtext-3CDbHg spotify-artist">by USAO, Laur</div>
```

Comment: I have one issue though, I can't change the html. I'm trying to theme something so all i have is CSS, would it be possible to do without changing the html?